# C++ operator[] magic

Tags: c++

I met a strange way of the appeal to an element of the array and thought it`s a mistake but it works. Can you explain how it works?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
  std::cout << 1[a];
}
```

Comment: What does that print?

Comment: `ptr[N]` is equivalent to `ptr + N`.  It follows that `N[ptr]` is `N + ptr`.  Hence `ptr[N] == N[ptr]`

Comment: @preciousbetine - it should print `2`

Comment: Duplicate of (C++ array[index] vs index[array])[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905724/c-arrayindex-vs-indexarray]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BaseAddr[ Offset ] = *( BaseAddr + Offset )
Offset[ BaseAddr ] = *( Offset + BaseAddr ) = *( BaseAddr + Offset )
```

Answer (score 10):

Expression `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a + b)` so in your example we have:

`1[a]` which can be written as `*(1 + a)` which is the same as `*(a + 1)` which is finally the same as `a[1]`

Comment: According to my brain's most vexing parsing, the first sentence is "Expression `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a + b)`" without the restriction "in your example", which is not necessarily true. For example, if `a` is a `std::vector`, `a[b]` is (usually) equivalent to `a.operator[](b)`, while `*(a + b)` does not compile. Still +1, though. :)

Comment: You're right, the operator[] can be overloaded and then the above may not be true.